# Get the all GET requests for a time range by the grep from the logs

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal, grep

How can I get all GET requests for the some time range from the log file?
As an example here is the record from log:

```
41.201.181.27 - [2019-04-06 18:20:13] "GET /popup.php?choix=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1692 "http://example.com/popup.php?choix=1" "Mozilla/4.0" "-"
```

I need extract all GET records for the 17th February from the 14:00 to 23:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With grep you can filter for the timestamp part of the date field. Something like this

```sh
grep -E '2019-02-17 (1[4-9]|2[0-2]|23:00)'
```

This will match the first and the last line as well so you have all the lines from the last second as well

Comment: And how after that i can filter byt the GET type of the request?

Comment: You can always pipe results from the grep something like `... | grep GET`

Comment: I've tried this one grep -E '2019-03-24 (\b14\b|\b23\b):' access.log | grep 'GET /brokers' | wc -l
and it's found only one record, but if i open by myself this log file i can fing at least 3 records by this conditions

Comment: Yeah, but i see at least two more record for the 16:00 and 20:00, so they are in the range but grep won't find it.

Comment: @SpaceBucks updated the regex with a range filter now

Comment: This will print lines between 23:01 and 23:59, which the OP may not want. Maybe use `(1[4-9]|2[0-2]|23:00)`?

Comment: Now i see, can you be so kind and give me an explanation why you divide a time range into two ranges?

Comment: 1400 till 1900 for the first range OR 2000 till 2200hrs for the second range and then just 2300 hrs for the third range @SpaceBucks

Comment: @SaifAsif Nitpicking, but I think you mean 1400-1959 or 2000-2259 or 2300.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://superuser.com/questions/439688/how-to-grep-a-log-file-within-a-specific-time-period) answer may help.

To filter for only `GET` requests, adding `.*GET` to whatever your regex is should work.